# How do I incorporate logic symbols in an "application.worksheetfunction.sumifs" line in vba?

Tags: vba

Super sorry if this has been answered, but for the life of me, I cannot find the answer.  I have some data on a worksheet and I am trying to sum values in column "H" based on the date in column "G".  If the date is between the 1st of the month and today as well as column "C" having certain text, then the values are summed.  Below is my line of code.

Please note that MCFws & DCFws are worksheet variables

Thank you!!

```
MCFws.Range("D4") = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DCFws.Range("H:H"), _
DCFws.Range("G:G"), DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) <= DCFws.Range("G:G"), DCFws.Range("G:G"), _
DCFws.Range("G:G") <= Date, DCFws.Range("C:C"), "ERISA") / 1000, "$#,##0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) <= DCFws.Range("G:G")`

Should be

```
">=" & DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
```

And

> `DCFws.Range("G:G") <= Date`

Should be

```
"<=" & Date
```

So:

```
MCFws.Range("D4") = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DCFws.Range("H:H"), _
    DCFws.Range("G:G"),">=" & DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), DCFws.Range("G:G"), _
    "<=" & Date, DCFws.Range("C:C"), "ERISA") / 1000, "$#,##0")
```

Comment: that's awesome! - i just need to remember to flip the signs on some other lines that were having the issue as well